# Android WorkManager doWork() run repeatedly even after task successfully completed

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I am using Android WorkManager(version 1.0.0-alpha13) to get some data from my server and store it on local database. Used following worker, without any operations and just returned success. doWork() run repeatedly,even after task successfully completed. Is it normal behaviour of Worker or is it any issue in this version?

**HomeRepository.kt**

```
val fetchVideosWorker = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(FetchVideosWorker::class.java)
                .build()
        val enqueue = WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(fetchVideosWorker)
```

**FetchVideosWorker.kt**

```
class FetchVideosWorker(context : Context, params : WorkerParameters) :  Worker(context,params) {

    override fun doWork(): Result {
        Log.d("youtubevideo","doWork")
        return Result.success()
    }
}
```

Comment: Any update for this issue?

Comment: How many times are you calling `enqueue()`? You'll get one run per `enqueue`

Comment: Sure..I called enqueue only once...